# Proxy authentication using CA5 cert & http certificate authentication

Tags: python, urllib3

I am new to Python, trying to read & parse logs of applications https url. My org has proxy setup. I am able to connect http url using basic_auth providing  &  & also by CA5 cert using below code 
    import urllib3

```
from urllib3 import ProxyManager, make_headers
# default_headers = make_headers(proxy_basic_auth='<username>:<password>')
# http = ProxyManager("http://<proxy_server>:<port>/", headers=default_headers)
http = ProxyManager("http://<proxy_server>:<port>/",cert_reqs='CERT_REQUIRED',ca_certs='<Windows path to .cer>')
r = http.request('GET','http://google.com')
print(r.data)
```

.pem certificate got saved as .cer on windows system. 
This is working as excepted and returnign google data.
Now while trying to use same for HTTPS url using below,

```
r = http.request('GET','https://google.com',verify='<same as above i.e. Windows path to .cer>')
```

It is failing with below errors,

```
.
.
OSError: Tunnel connection failed: 502 notresolvable
.
.
.
urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='google.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: / (Caused by SSLError(SSLError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:749)'),))
```

As the log files are keeping updating, might need to stream it; Suggestion on this is highly appreciated.

Using **Python 3.6.0 |Anaconda 4.3.1 (64-bit)** on **Windows 7**.